# Can I ping/send ICMP through TOR?

Tags: proxy, ping, tor, socks-proxy, socks

1. Is that possible?
2. Does Tor use Application Layer SOCKS4/SOCKS5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you currently can't send ICMP through Tor:

https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#TransportIPnotTCP

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/1855

Tor itself does not use SOCKS.  It is just a TCP proxy.  You use an Onion router to handle the SOCKS part:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)#Originating_traffic

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answer already mentioned: ICMP is not possible over Tor. But, nowadays Tor offers a SOCKS5 proxy by default.

But if you just want to test connectivity over Tor, you could use TCP-based tools similar to `ping` (referring to your question being tagged `ping` although `ping` wasn't mentioned in the posting itself):

- [echoping](https://github.com/bortzmeyer/echoping/) (generic TCP and UDP)
- [httping](http://www.vanheusden.com/httping) (HTTP and HTTPS)
- ssh-ping (SSH, including testing for successful logins, e.g. with SSH keys; part of [ssh-tools](https://github.com/vaporup/ssh-tools/))

I'm using the latter as replacement for pinging servers over Tor before backing them up over SSH over Tor.

You either need to point these tools to connect to the SOCKS5 proxy of your local Tor daemon (usually on `127.0.0.1:9050`) or use `torify`.

Note: Not all tools mentioned here were available when the question  originally was posted, but the question is still valid nowadays. Hence a modern answer for an old question. :-)